# Cant connect sql server from another computer

Tags: sql-server-2012, database-connection

Currently, I am using SQL server 2012 and running in window 7 64 bit.

My question is

> How can I connect this server from another computer (window 10 64
>   bit)?

What have I done?

- My server name is NB-1608-001\SQLEXPRESS2 and I already enable TCP/IP status and Name Pipes status and Shared Memory status
- I already set TCP port 1433 for IP4 and IPAll.
- I already enable "Allow remote connection to this server" for this server
- I already enable "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode"
- The two computer are on the same network

I created UDL file in window 10 computer (I set server name to :"\NB-1608-001\SQLEXPRESS2")and try to connect to sql server but this say:

> Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider :
>   Unspecified error

After searching some solution on google,

- I created InBound and Outbound rule for IP 1433 in Window 7 Computer

But it's still not working.

I tried another way for make sure whether this two computer is connected or not.

I typed "\NB-1608-001" in network and this said

> Windows cannot access \NB-1608-001

After Diagnose,It said

> file and print sharing resource (NB-1608-001) is online but isnt
>   responding to connection attempts.

So I assume the two computers are connected.

Is there still another solution?

My main reason is to run the c# app and connect to another computer's SQL server.

Thanks

Comment: Run an nmap to the servers ip address on port 3306 and look if its open

Answer (score 0):

(some notes: 1433 is a TCP port not an IP, you have to put two backslash \\ for UNC path but maybe this is a StackOverflow escape problem)

I suggest to disable the firewall **just for testing purpose** to all firewall profiles (maybe you set inbound rule only for private profile and your network is flagged as public).

I would try a ping to the machine name to be sure that its name is resolved by the client.

I would check in the Sql server Configuration manager that TCP client protocols is enabled for both SQL Native clients (32 and 64bit) and TCP/IP under Protocols Network Configuration.

You did not say what is your client, I would try to connect with SQL Server Management Studio, just to be sure this is not a problem related to your client.

This reading can be useful:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2005/05/05/how-to-configure-express-to-accept-remote-connections/

Comment: Thanks. When i ping like "ping NB-1608-001",It 0% Lost.

Comment: What client are you using?

Comment: In my SQL server configuration manager, Protocols for SQLEXPRESS2 only exists in SQL Server Network Configuration (32 bit), Not exist in SQL Server Network Configuration.

Comment: My client is window 10 computer.

Comment: Maybe your server is 32bit, this is normal, in my case I have Networkconfig protocols only for 64bit and not for 32. But SQL native clients should be se for both.

Comment: I mean SQL Server client. How can you connet to sql server? SQL Manager studio?

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding, SQL Management Studio is running on Window 7 computer (assume like server) and Window 10 computer is very new and there is nothing (assume like client). Is there something need to run in window 10 computer?

Comment: SQL Management Studio is not the server itself, it is a client software to manage/query the database! You can install SQL Management Studio to another machine and connet it to the server machine. I cannot understand WHAT you have to connects to your server. I suggested to try to connet SQL Manament Studio from outside your server machine to be sure it is not a client problem.

Comment: The main reason is to run the c# client-server application that application is using SQL server. I don't need SQL Management Studio in the client because I don't manage the SQL server from the client. Normally I just need C# exe file and config file which include connection string. In the connection string, containing server name and database name. But now, I cant connect even from UDL file. So I cant run my application in client.

Comment: I suggested to install SQL Studio to try with another client, if you have a bug in the C# or an error in the connection string, SQL Studio should work and you can be sure that it is not a server problem.